# How to clone GtkWindow with its content?

Tags: c, gtk3, glade

I am using C and Glade with GTK 3. I want to create a simple programming language. I created the basics: code editor, output window etc. But when the user closes the output window, and tries to re-open, this message shows:

```
(ltc:3443): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GObject'
(ltc:3443): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_class_list_properties: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT_CLASS (class)' failed
```

I think the problem is caused by that when the user closes the window, its structure also gets destroyed on the memory.

How do I clone the window? I tried the simple GObject cloning algorithm, but it doesn't clone window content.

Is it possible to make the window not get destroyed when closing or clone it?

Comment: Please post a minimum working example. Also I don't see any debugging statements in your output, just the errors. Try stepping through your code with gdb. It is an invaluable tool. It should quickly identify where your fault is; something that is very hard to do from only what you have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you want, instead of cloning the window, is to make sure that it is not destroyed when closed, and instead hidden.

Try connecting to the `delete-event` signal and using `gtk_widget_hide_on_delete()` as the signal handler, or calling it in your signal handler.